# Execute function after the user finishes using the slider

Tags: javascript, slider, nouislider

I want to execute some function after the user has finished using the slider and not while the slider is being manipulated.

Only after the handle stops, then start the function.
I remember doing this using setTimeout and clearTimer but I don't remember how to do it exactly.

```
$('#slider').on('slide', function(){ 
   some_function();
});
```

Note that I am using [**nouislider**](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) and not jquery.

Comment: NoUISlider is a jQuery plugin, so you *are* using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you want a callback on the `set` event, which occurs when the user stops sliding.

```
$('#slider').on('set', function(){ 
   some_function();
});
```

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/

Answer (score 0):

Try listening for 'change' event.